# How to rename a file and overwrite existing in VBS?

Tags: vbscript, rename, overwrite

I already an existing vbs script to take one file (titled "Running_12345.xlsx") from one location and put it in the folder titled "Folder". This is an hourly file that has a long name based on what time it was run.

Now, I want to rename the file just "Running.xlsx" to remove the constantly changing file name. Initially, this code works, but for any subsequent occurence, it fails because the "Running.xlsx" file has already been renamed once and now already exists. How do I add overwrite logic to this code:

```
dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set oFldr = fso.getfolder("folder")

for each ofile in oFldr.Files
 if lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "xlsx" then
  ofile.name = "Running.xlsx"
  Exit for
 end if
Next
```

Comment: maybe have you several xlsx files and one already nammed Running.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Duh, just delete the file first. The code below does what I want:

```
dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set oFldr = fso.getfolder("C:\Users\...\Desktop\MosaicTransforms\")

fso.DeleteFile("C:\Users\...\Desktop\MosaicTransforms\MosaicFile.xlsx")



for each ofile in oFldr.Files
 if lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "xlsx" then
  ofile.name = "MosaicFile.xlsx"
  Exit for
 end if
Next
```